# What's the best way to fix issues in RazorEngine?

Tags: razorengine

I am trying to understand what the process is for fixing minor issues in RazorEngine. I ran into issue 133 [1] where included views don't inherit the viewbag from the parent view. The fix is really simple (included in the issue description) but I am not sure how best to go about getting it committed.

Any suggestions?

Thanks!

Henrik

[1] https://github.com/Antaris/RazorEngine/issues/133

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the owner of that repository has not been active on GitHub in several months.  However, their [last public comment](https://github.com/Antaris/RazorEngine/issues/113#issuecomment-20725532) indicated a willingness to add contributors to the RazorEngine project.  If it were me, my next step would be to contact the maintainer directly and ask for write access to the repository.

Answer (score 0):

The best way is to create a pull request with a new test that fails pre-fix and passes post-fix. That way it is really simple for the project maintainer to automatically include your fix and put out a new release.